# Displaying each section's elements on scroll, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `opacity: 0` elements inside sections. And trying to make `opacity: 1` those if their section fully visible in the window. The code I wrote is below. It has flaws.

```js
$(window).scroll( function(){
    $('.parts').each(function(i){        
        var sectionBottom = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var windowBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();            
        if( windowBottom > (sectionBottom + 300) ){
            $("h1").css("opacity", "1");
            $("h2").css("opacity", "1");
            $("h3").css("opacity", "1");
        }            
    }); 
});
```

```css
.parts {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.part1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.part2 {
  background-color: red;
}
.part3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
h1,h2,h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="parts part1">
  <h1>this is the el of 1</h1>
</section>
<section class="parts part2">
  <h2>this is the el of 1</h2>
</section>
<section class="parts part3">
  <h3>this is the el of 1</h3>
</section>
```

It displays all elements at once, at the same time. how can I make elements display only their section visible in the window.

Comment: can you elaborate on your question more it's hard to understand? What exactly is the issue ? and whats wrong with the example?

Comment: I tried to make it more clear. could you check the it again? @saurabh the jquery code is displays all elements at once, but i want to display if element's parent(section) visible in the window

Comment: What flaws you think your code have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slight issue with in the scroll function. The scroll function is simply checking for `windowBottom > (sectionBottom + 300)` and if it's true it simply makes everything visible for other section as well.

To solve this on scroll check if that section is visible in the window or not and then make the elements visible(`opacity: 1`) inside it.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.parts').each(function(i, ele) {
    console.log(isElemIntoView(ele));
    console.log();
    if (isElemIntoView(ele)) {
      $(ele.className + " *").css("opacity", "1");
    }
  });
});


function isElemIntoView(elem) {
  var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

  var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

  return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but when I debug it, this part is doesn't work.       `$(ele.className + " *").css("opacity", "1");` I think the problem is `className`

Comment: but did some changes at that part like `$(el).children().addClass()` so it's working now thank you for the showing the way. it helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```js
sectionDisplay();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  sectionDisplay();
});

function sectionDisplay() {
  $('.parts').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).position().top - 100 <= $(window).scrollTop()) {
      $(this).children().animate({
        opacity: 1
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.parts {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.part1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.part2 {
  background-color: red;
}

.part3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="parts part1">
  <h1>this is the el of 1</h1>
</section>
<section class="parts part2">
  <h2>this is the el of 1</h2>
</section>
<section class="parts part3">
  <h3>this is the el of 1</h3>
</section>
<section class="parts part1">
  <h1>this is the el of 1</h1>
</section>
<section class="parts part2">
  <h2>this is the el of 1</h2>
</section>
```